# Download a PNG file served as binary/octet-stream

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, blob, content-type

### [image]steps that will reproduce the problem :

I am saving a Blob object as form data using a service and I am receiving the response as content-type: application/octet-stream as in attached image

**What is the expected result?**

- To download and view the the application/octet-stream as a image into local machine and view it using applications

**What happens instead?**

able to download the file as image but it says we dont support this file format though its (ex:image.png)

```
function add() {
  $.ajax({
  url: 'https://localhost:3000/upload/sampleImage.png',
  type: 'GET',
  success: function (data) {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.style.display = 'none';
    link.download = "sample image";
     link.href =  
       'data:' +
       'image/png' +
       ';base64,' +
       window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(data)));
    link.click();
  },
  error: function (request, error) {
    alert("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
  }
});
```

}

Any ways to download the file and preview it successfully

Comment: you mean you want to http get the file in your folder and download it ? and why are you using $ ajax in angular ....we can use httpclient right??

Comment: I wanted to directly download the file after receiving the response. for test purpose i used $ajax, yes can use httpclient as well

Answer (score 4):

Set the **responseType as blob** in request

Using HttpClient:

```
this.http.get("https://localhost:3000/upload/sampleImage.png",{responseType:'blob'}).subscribe((img)=>{
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.style.display = 'none';
        link.download = "sample image";
         link.href =window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
        link.click();
  });
```

Now using $.ajax(not recommended,avoid using it) specify the dataType as blob and use `window.URL.createObjectURL(data)` to create URL

```
 $.ajax({
  url: 'https://localhost:3000/upload/sampleImage.png',
  type: 'GET',
  xhrFields:{
            responseType: 'blob'
        },
  success: function (data) {
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.style.display = 'none';
    link.download = "sample image";
    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/png'});
    link.href =window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.click();
  },
  error: function (request, error) {
    alert("Request: " + JSON.stringify(request));
  }
```

Comment: though the repsonse is success from service, its going into error block -> console.log(error) gives me parse error .. when i tried the above code

Comment: which method did you try angular one or ajax?

Comment: i have used ajax method.

Comment: xhrFields:{
                responseType: 'blob'
            }, I've updated the answer

Comment: modified as mentioned, it prints [object Blob]  and there is a type error `(index):41 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
    at Object.success ((index):41)
    at fire (jquery-3.4.1.js:3291)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.4.1.js:3421)
    at done (jquery-3.4.1.js:9533)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.4.1.js:9785)`

Comment: got this error `(index):41 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
    at Object.success ((index):41)`

Comment: var blob = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/png'});
        link.href =window.URL.createObjectURL(blob); try modifying your code with this.I have updated the answer